# Good resource on tessellation subdivison pattern

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx, tessellation

I have the need to replicate GPU tessellation on the CPU (ie get the same uvw coordinates on the CPU side as I will get on the GPU from the tessellator).
The reason for this is rather complicated, but simply put I have an algorithm that stores data per tessellation point, and to calculate it in the first place I need the uvw coordinates on the CPU.

I have googled a lot for the exact details of the tessellation pattern, but I only find very vague texts speaking about it in a general nature, the best one being this one: http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-12/

Is the reason for the lack of texts on this that it's vendor dependent, or have I simply not found the not found the right page?

I'm interested in texts both on the OpenGL and DX11 implementation, if they differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also very interested by [tessellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation_%28computer_graphics%29), and specifically [subdivision surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface) some time ago. This is a very complicated topic. It was researched from early 70th and it's still in research.

It isn't clear if you want to re-implement whole shader tessellation pipeline (which I think will take years for a single programmer) or just a single subdivision algorithm (or even algorith that isn't subdivision).

Anyway, there is some links about subdivision:

**Theory**

Typically we implement subdivision surfaces in tessellation shaders using [Catmull–Clark subdivision surface algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface). You can find some papers from original authors in Google. There is main one:

"[Recursively generated B-spline surfaces on arbitrary topological meshes](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/CS284/PAPERS/CatmullClark_SDSurf.pdf)" (year 1978, PDF)

**Closer to code**

Check papers of those cool guys from Microsoft Research:

- [Charles Loop](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/) - (BTW, author of [another subdiv algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_subdivision_surface)), purely mathematical stuff
- [Hugues Hoppe](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/) - Look for "progressive meshes", much more close to software

**Even more closer to code.**

You can find some libraries on the web. When I searched a while ago, there was a dozen of libs, that implemented subdivision on CPU. I didn't look they much, because I was interested in GPU implementation. The keyword for search is "subdivision lib" =)

The most interesting one is [Pixar's OpenSubdiv](http://graphics.pixar.com/opensubdiv/overview.html). Take a look at their code.

Also look at "NVIDIA Instanced Tessellation" Sample ([DirectX](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/direct3d/samples.html), [OpenGL](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/opengl/samples.html)). They've implemented tessellation pipelne in Vertex and Geometry shaders.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I think this might be just what I was looking for. I'm not looking to reimplement the whole tessellation pipeline.What I want is to implement only the integer subdivision pattern, and I can also limit myself to things like "only power-of-2 tessellation factors" etc.